# Please help me insert this example into Mathematica to illustrate the transformation

Tags: complex, coordinate-transformation, mathematica-online

Please help me insert this example into Mathematica to illustrate the transformation[image]

Comment: What have you tried?  You would do better to attempt to do this homework problem yourself and then ask for help when you encounter specific difficulties.

Comment: @misoon:  Nice job deriving that.  If I have a function w(z) of a complex variable coded in Mathematica say as as w[z_]:=2 z^2 and I want to plot w(z) in the w-plane as z traverses some contour in the z-plane say z(a+iy), then one way is to use ParametricPlot.  Type in ParametricPlot, hover over it, press the "I" icon and study and execute some of the examples then try to code  the following commands:  w[z_]:=2 z^2; a=2; ParametricPlot[{Re[w[z]],Im[w[z]]}/.z->a+I y,{y,-10,10}].  If you want to know what Re is for example, do the "I" for information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note,there is a gap in the circle where the line extends to infinity. I use "Manipulate" to adjust the length of the line:

```
w[z_] = 4/z;
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[ReIm[w[4 + t I]], {t, -m, m}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-0.5, 0.5}}]
 , {{m, 10}, 1, 50}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your work, but I need to clarify the shift between graphs

Comment: What shifts? Do you mean the scaling of the Graphs? You may need the option: , `PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-0.5, 0.5}}`

Comment: actually, I do not have any idea about the program and was asked to use it. This is the objective of the duty:
Our goal is to use the flexible Mathematica to illustrate and facilitate related conformal mapping and solving mathematics problems by using conformal mapping and the Mathematica.